# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "bug_report_model" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to run a simple java play 2.5 app on heroku. I am able to open the home page which generally means that connection to the database is successful. But when ever i try to call the route to add a dummy value to the table it shows

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[ERROR: relation "bug_report_model" does not exist\n   Position: 13]]
```

The code to add a value to the database is

```
 public Result enterDummyTextInDb() {
    BugReportModel model = new BugReportModel();
    model.save();
    return ok(Json.toJson(model));
}
```

The Model class is

```
@Entity
public class BugReportModel extends Model {
@Id
private Long id;
private Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

public BugReportModel() {
}

public static Finder<Long, BugReportModel> find = new Model.Finder<Long, BugReportModel>(BugReportModel.class);

public static List<BugReportModel> findAll() {
    return BugReportModel.find.orderBy("id").findList();
}


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(Long timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

}

found something for spring/hibernate that said that the table isnt created and so we have to add

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

but not sure about it for java play 2.5

Comment: is the table "bug_report_model" exists in the DB? perhaps it is called something else?

Comment: there is no table in the db right now. Like i mentioned in the end. found something related to spring/hibernate but cant figure out how to create the db in java play. 
     found something in the getting started scala play heroku code but not sure how to implement it in java

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your app to run evolutions by making your Procfile like this:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/myapp -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

For more info see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionHeroku